# SHA1 Filter in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

How can I filter my POST data to be in SHA1 value using Zend Filter? I'm trying to compare current plain password that user submitted to a SHA1 value in my database.

I'm using Identical Validator to compare the value (which I got from Database before rendering the form to user). I'm using `processAjax` to validate all the form values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create your own filter to do that:

```
  class Sha1Filter implements Zend_Filter_Interface
  {
      public function filter($value)
      {
                    return sha1($value);
      }
  }
```

After that you can add it as any other filter

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.writing_filters.html

Answer (score 1):

zerkms' answer is correct.

But, I would recommend against using filters to do this. You should use Zend_Auth for this. Simple example:

```
$adapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($db);
$adapter->setTableName('users');
$adapter->setIdentityColumn('username');
$adapter->setCredentialColumn('password');
$adapter->setCredentialTreatment('SHA1(password)');
$adapter->setIdentity($form->getValue('username'));
$adapter->setCredential($form->getValue('password'));

$result = $auth->authenticate($adapter);
switch ($result->getCode()) {
    case Zend_Auth_Result::FAILURE_IDENTITY_NOT_FOUND:
        // do something
        break;
    case Zend_Auth_Result::FAILURE_CREDENTIAL_INVALID:
        // do something
        break;
    case Zend_Auth_Result::SUCCESS:
        // do something
        break;
    default:
        // do something
        break;
}
```

Comment: I'm actually going to use it for the user's control panel so that the user can change his/her password. But thanks for the code, we'll use it for authentication :)